# Seguir ejecución de script jQuery después de detectar un clic de un botón

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cuento con un fragmento de script de jQuery. Este fragmento está compuesto por un [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventSource), el cual hace peticiones al back cada 3 segundos, este me retorna un JSON con los valores correctos.

Las peticiones de EventSource son una tras otra cada 3 segundos y me gustaría poder 'pausar' esas peticiones hasta que el usuario de clic en algún botón de la página web.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo podría 'detener' el script de jQuery y que al momento de detectar un clic de algún botón, el script se reanudará?

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario detener todo el script, solo necesitas cerrar la conexión y volver a conectar cuando se detecte algún movimiento por parte del usuario.

```
const Connection = (url) => {
  let instance = null;
  let listeners = [];

  return {
    connect() {
      instance = new EventSource(url);
      listeners.forEach(({ name, fn }) => {
        instance.addListener(name, fn, false);
      });
    },
    disconnect: () => {
      instance.disconnect();
      instance = null;
    },
    addListener: (listener) => {
      listeners.push(listener);
    },
    removeListener: ({ name, fn }) => {
      instance.removeListener(name, fn, false);
      listeners = listeners.filter(({ name, fn }) => name !== name);
    },
  };
};
```

Estableces al conexión y añades los listeners:

```
const conn = Connection('url');
conn.addEventListener({
  name: 'algo',
  fn: () => console.log('bla'),
});
```

Y puedes conectarte y desconectarte a demanda:

```
conn.connect();
conn.disconnect();
conn.connect();
```